# Empty /boot/efi after a fresh install of elementary OS 5.0 (Juno)

Tags: boot, release-juno, uefi, efi, secure-boot

I did a fresh install of Juno on a laptop that I previously used with Loki. However, after the installation finishes and the laptop reboots, I get just black screen with a message about missing boot device (see screen 1).

[image: Screen 1]

After pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I get to a second screen with list of two options - shim and grub. Choosing any of them returns me to screen 1. In other words - **I cannot boot into the freshly installed system**.

[image: Screen 2]

If I insert live USB (created using the [MultiBoot tool](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) that I successfully use for years), it sometimes shows a new option on the list with name of my USB drive. Selecting it sends me to MultiBoot menu, where I can boot into my live Linux distributions.

If I start a live session of, e.g., elementary OS, I can see that the */boot/efi* folder of the installed system is completely empty. This shouldn't be the case as I have UEFI and secure boot enabled (I had this setup in Loki too).

I remember that I had booting problems on this machine also after installing Loki, however based on my notes and weak memory I solved them quite easily by just selecting both shim and grub options consecutively. This however doesn't have any effect in Juno.

Is there a way to fix this e.g. by copying the missing files from somewhere in the live session? And if so, from where can I copy these files?

**System:** Acer Aspire One Cloudbook 11 - netbook with 32 GB eMMC storage with those weird partition names like `mmcblk0` or `mmcblk0boot0` instead of (I guess) `sda` or `sda1` (respectively). `sudo parted -l` shows two partitions on `mmcblk0` - one fat32-formated EFI partition and one ext4-formated partition with the installed system.

## Update:

I tried to run Boot Repair utility from LiveUSB and it didn't work, the log is here:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/f72xMvBTtn/
(dropbox backup: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vk16exwmcmorj5x/boot-repair_cloudbook.txt?dl=0)

I also found a thread on Linux Mint forums with almost identical symptoms (Acer laptop, same error message, no access to BIOS, only his OS is 16.04-based):
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=269299

However I cannot access BIOS (I don't have older version of Juno available, like he had with LM) so I cannot use his solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solved

My main problem was that I was unable to access the BIOS, as the normal method for my laptop didn't work (i.e., when the laptop is OFF, press & hold <kbd>F2</kbd> and turn it ON, keep holding <kbd>F2</kbd> until the BIOS shows up).

However, today after some new desperate attempts with boot-repair, I tried enter the BIOS the way it's normally done on other laptops (i.e., turning it on and *then* press <kbd>F2</kbd> like crazy) - and voilà - it worked!

In the BIOS, I had to do a few things suggested in the link to [Linux Mint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint) forum:

1. Reset Secure boot to factory settings
2. Erase Secure boot configuration
3. <kbd>F10</kbd> to save and reboot (this was **crucial**)
4. Enter the BIOS again and select three EFI files from my EMMC drive (from within the *ubuntu* folder) and give them *different* descriptions:

- shimx64.efi
- grubx64.efi
- fwupx64.efi
- *Note: I've used name of each file without "x64.efi" as description. But it was important to have the descriptions unique.*

5. <kbd>F10</kbd> to save and a final reboot.

After this, I was greeted with the elementary OS logo :)