# Juno system-installation Acer Aspire ES1-732-P3A8

Tags: system-installation, release-juno, uefi

I read this : 
[Empty /boot/efi after fresh install of Juno](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/empty-boot-efi-after-fresh-install-of-juno)

And was quiet confident, but, it doesn't work for me, cause I can't :

> - Enter BIOS again and select 3 EFI files from my EMMC drive (from within the **ubuntu folder**) and give them *different* descriptions:
>
>   - shimx64.efi
>   - grubx64.efi
>   - fwupx64.efi
>   - *Note: I've used name of each file without "x64.efi" as description.

Because there is no option in this BIOS to add anything...
And no more BIOS/Legacy mode available -- Only (U)EFI...

Any clue ?

As an expert-mode install?

An idea to install rEFInd and not Grub (who is responsible of a systematic hang ...)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: As clarifiaction.. Or you have BIOS or UEFI... BIOS was the old system now is UEFI. I know people still call it BIOS but they are not the same and you have one or another. For example UEFI in legacy mode will act as BIOS but is still UEFI. https://fossbytes.com/uefi-bios-gpt-mbr-whats-difference/

Comment: You're absolutely right, Sebastian : just a misuse of language ... Sorry !

Answer (score 0):

Hmm not completely sure but you should try running [boot-repair](https://launchpad.net/~yannubuntu/+archive/ubuntu/boot-repair) from your USB boot disk - that has solved all of my problems so far.

Answer (score 0):

i have instalation in ACER-E5745G and its okay not problem, im just make little setting in my bios.

1. make secure boot is off
2. add new boot list (linux) to run
3. make a new boot to top